# What is the risk of shutting down CMD and aborting chkdsk C: /r near end of stage 5?

Tags: windows, command-line, chkdsk

I'm in South Africa and we have a huge issue with power supply. We experience 2 to 3 stages of load/power shedding a day for 2 to 4hrs at a time.  My Lenovo ThinkPad x220 battery is useless so i have to work when plugged in. The other day we had unscheduled load shedding whilst I was busy working after taking a week to correct a windows startup issue. Because I could not power off in time, when I tried to start up later, I got BSoD and cannot enable safe mode.  In fact, none of the other advanced options/troubleshooting for windows work. So, I'm trying CMD.

I started CMD `CHKDSK C: /r` at 13h00 today. It got to stage 5 - 82% complete for stage and 83% total completion by 18h56 - we had notification of load shedding for 19h00 so instead of letting it run until the power supply shut down my PC and task - I closed CMD at this point and shut down my PC properly, thinking this option less risky than a forced power and task interruption due to load shedding.

What I'd like to know is what are the possible risks of me having done this?

And;
What other options can I try / cmd windows repair can I try without resetting my PC and reinstalling windows as I couldn't do a backup.  Would the last restore point work in the case of me having no other option but reset and reinstall?
(Sorry to ask a stupid question, just examining all options)

Comment: "All options" should include backups & not rely on restore points or chkdsk.

Comment: As @Tetsujin suggests, make a backup -- or more usefully, make a **full disk image** on a regular basis, which allows you to recover data *and* operating system *and* software *and* all settings.  That said, **get a battery or UPS**. A small UPS for a laptop should be <900 ZAR, and many can signal the PC to shut down gracefully when the battery is low.

Comment: Also note: chkdsk's job is not to save your files, it is to restore the filesystem integrity. It will sacrifice any & all of your data to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 2):

`chkdsk` is a powerful command and interrupting it is not recommended.

I found an answer that fits your case in the post
[Is it safe to cancel chkdsk?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-it-safe-to-cancel-chkdsk/b3434bf5-219c-44e2-9e44-7a5cfd51715d)

> It is safe to cancel Check Disk in phase 4 or 5, it is not safe to cancel in phase 1, 2 or 3 as that can result in data loss and/or bricking your system

As you were already in phase 5, you seem to be safe.

In the future, either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> should stop the scan in
a relatively "friendly" manner that has the best chance of not causing
an issue.

Power outages and other "unfriendly" methods are to be avoided.
If your area is subject to power problems without notice,
I suggest getting a UPS with battery that will give you some minutes
in which to shut down the computer in an orderly manner.

If your disk is experiencing issues, I recommend taking a backup image
of the disk with a boot media for restoring it.
An example is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
with its
[boot media](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, and assuming you can do this, you should have a small UPS for your computer. This will allow you to shut down safely and not compromise your data.

Second, with respect to CHKDSK, start it and let it run overnight. If, at that point it has not finished, you can attempt to cancel it. In some cases that may restart CHKDSK.

Two outcomes possible:

(1) All well and no permanent file damage.

(2) CHKDSK stopped on damaged files and cannot recover.  Those files are gone and not any practical recovery.

The second option may require reinstalling Windows depending on the damage